# How to get initials from fullname in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string

I have a simple table:

```
id | fullname
---------------------------
 1 | Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich
---------------------------
 2 | Petrov Petr Petrovich
---------------------------
 3 | Alym kyzy Ainura
```

I need transform them into something like this:

```
id | name_initials
--------------------
 1 | Ivanov I. I.
--------------------
 2 | Petrov P. P.
--------------------
 3 | Alym k. A.
```

I can easily make it via PHP, but MySQL is about data manipulation. I think, it might (and MUST) be done with DBMS only.

How can it be done via pure SQL?
Should I write stored function for this, or is there any shorter way?

Regards.

Comment: Yes, a function is needed. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301081/get-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sql-string

Comment: You could take a look at  the string functions and see how far you get with `substr`, `locate` and/or `substring_index`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius thanks for your opinion / final argument.

Comment: @towi Since when MS SQL Server-related questions are equal to MySQL Server questions? Could you please specify?

Comment: @CORRUPT I am sorry, I overlooked that. I removed the *duplication comment* generated by the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  fullname,
  CONCAT_WS(' ',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 1),
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(fullname)-LENGTH(REPLACE(fullname,' ',''))>2 THEN
      CONCAT(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', -3), 1), '.')
    END,
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(fullname)-LENGTH(REPLACE(fullname,' ',''))>1 THEN
      CONCAT(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', -2), 1), '.')
    END,
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(fullname)-LENGTH(REPLACE(fullname,' ',''))>0 THEN
      CONCAT(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', -1), 1), '.')
    END) shortname
FROM
  Names
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de8bf/1). This query will support at maximum four names.

Comment: I like your approach, but there is really a lot of places, where I will need to correct code, if I use it. I've upvoted your answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok, regardless of my solution, I'm fully agree, that your answer is more easy applicable in most cases. Accepted, for future visitors. Thanks again. I don't even knew, that this is possible in direct query without stored functions.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with stored function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `getNameInitials`(`fullname` VARCHAR(70))
RETURNS VARCHAR(70)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE `result` VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE `position` TINYINT;

DECLARE `separator` VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ';
DECLARE `append` VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '.';

DECLARE `buffer` VARCHAR(10);

SET `fullname` = CONCAT(TRIM(`fullname`), `separator`);
SET `position` = LOCATE(`separator`, `fullname`);

IF NOT `position`
THEN RETURN TRIM(`fullname`);
END IF;

SET `result`   = LEFT(`fullname`, `position` - 1);

cycle: LOOP
    SET `fullname` = SUBSTR(`fullname`, `position` + 1);
    SET `position` = LOCATE(`separator`, `fullname`);

    IF NOT `position` OR NOT LENGTH(`fullname`)
    THEN LEAVE cycle;
    END IF;

    SET `buffer` = CONCAT(LEFT(`fullname`, 1), `append`);
    SET `result` = CONCAT_WS(`separator`, `result`, `buffer`);
END LOOP cycle;

RETURN `result`;
END
```

Checked with:

```
SELECT
    getNameInitials(`fullname`) as `name`
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        'Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich' as `fullname`
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Alym kyzy Ainura'
    ) `sub`;
```

And got following result:

```
'Ivanov I. I.'
'Alym k. A.'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getNameInitials`(`fullname` VARCHAR(500), `separator` VARCHAR(1)) RETURNS varchar(70) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE `result` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE `position` TINYINT;



SET `fullname` = TRIM(`fullname`);

SET `position` = LOCATE(`separator`, `fullname`);

IF NOT `position`
THEN RETURN LEFT(`fullname`,1);
END IF;

SET `fullname` = CONCAT(`fullname`,`separator`);
SET `result` = LEFT(`fullname`, 1);

cycle: LOOP
    SET `fullname` = SUBSTR(`fullname`, `position` + 1);
    SET `position` = LOCATE(`separator`, `fullname`);

    IF NOT `position` OR NOT LENGTH(`fullname`)
    THEN LEAVE cycle;
    END IF;

    SET `result` = CONCAT(`result`,LEFT(`fullname`, 1));
   -- SET `result` = CONCAT_WS(`separator`, `result`, `buffer`);
END LOOP cycle;

RETURN upper(`result`);
END
```

1.Execute this function in mysql. 2.this will create a function. Now you can use this function anywhere you want.

```
 SELECT `getNameInitials`('Kaleem Ul Hassan', ' ') AS `NameInitials`;
```

3. The above getNameInitails first parameter is string you want to filter and second is the spectator character on which you want to separate you string. 4. In above example 'Kaleem Ul Hassan' is name and i want to get initials and my separator is space ' '.