# Masking Name Column

Tags: sql, db2

I need to mask the account number and name data from my reports. My table looks like this

| ACC_NUM | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 100000111 | THISISMYNAME |
| 100000522 | EVAN DIMASATRIO |
| 100000631 | THIS IS MYNAME |
| 100000851 | RAUL HOLMES |
| 100000999 | RAUL HOLMES AGUSTINA |

I need to show the last 3 digits for the `ACC_NUM` column and the first 3 digits from every word for the `NAME` column. I can use `CONCAT('xxxxxxx', RIGHT(ACC_NUM, 3))` for the `ACC_NUM` column, but I can't find a way to mask the `NAME` column.

My expected output is something like this

| MASK_ACC | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| xxxxxxx111 | THIXXXXX |
| xxxxxxx522 | EVAXXXXX DIMXXXXX |
| xxxxxxx631 | THIXXXXX IS MYNXXXXX |
| xxxxxxx851 | RAUXXXXX HOLXXXXX |
| xxxxxxx851 | RAUXXXXX HOLXXXXX AGUXXXXX |

This is my dbfiddle link: https://dbfiddle.uk/3K_MpRoE

Comment: Do you mean "first 3 characters / letters from every word in the name column"? What are the formal rules? For the row with num 631 your output does not make sense to me. Why is "IS" not masked? Why do you always have XXXXX at the end. Add the formal masking rules to your question.

Comment: @data_henrik it makes sense to me since "IS" only contains two words, so it shoould not be masked

Comment: Is there a max of name parts? The row with 631 shows that strings can expand. What is the max column size?

Comment: Hi! Just found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301081/get-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sql-string

Comment: Dependent on your version of Db2, you may be interested in RCAC: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=security-row-column-access-control-rcac

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it everyone, I will use this query

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(NAME, '([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]+)', '\1****')
```

This is the dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/4QGiz9RF

Comment: Based on your db2fiddle, you are not following the rules you stated in your question. "IS" is not masked.

Comment: How come I'm not following my rules? I need to show the last 3 digits for the ACC_NUM column and the first 3 digits from every word for the NAME column.

Comment: In your sample data you show "IS" -> "XXXXX", but the fiddle output has something different. That's why I asked for formal rules and also how you deal with expanding data. Anyway, your problem.

Comment: I mean, I stated in my question that "My expected output is something like this"  not "exactly like this". Sorry for the confusion tho.

Answer (score -1):

Select substring(x.acc_num,1,0)+'*****'+substring(x.acc_num,len(x.acc_num)-2,len(x.acc_num)) from acc x

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).